# SharePoint Online data limits

Tags: sharepoint-online

We are considering adding SharePoint On-line to our cloud portfolio. We currently have eCal Services and Azure AD. 
Does anyone know the storage limits for:

1. SharePoint online plan1
2. SharePoint online plan2
3. Office 365 Enterprise E3

Thanks

Comment: Just a remark: Keep in mind that SharePoint Online and Office 365 are limited not only in terms of data but also in terms of features. For instance, none of them implements the CMIS interoperability protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be **1 TB per organization plus 0.5 GB per license purchased**.
Have  a look at this [link](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/SharePoint-Online-limits-and-quotas-8f34ff47-b749-408b-abc0-b605e1f6d498?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB) for more details (Click on the 'Limits for current Office 365 for business plans').

Remember that you will also get 1 TB of OneDrive storage per user.

Comment: About 100 users need access to SharePoint Online (these are mainly external to the organisation i.e Partners). Is there a way to divide storage or maybe have 2 tenants linked? Otherwise the 1TB organisation data may get consumed by externals?

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.jijitechnologies.com/blogs/how-to-set-storage-quota-for-office365-groups-in-sharepoint-online.  You can't limit document libraries storage.  The only way is not to give external access to add/upload files on the site.  You can also create multiple site collections and allocate storage limit to that particular site collection.

Comment: Is it true if I want to give an external user read access no licence is needed for that user?
i.e. licence only needed if user can read and write?

Comment: Yes, you don't need to assign licence to external users. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Office-365/Sharepoint-Online-users-access-without-licenses/td-p/14817

Comment: read and write?

Comment: Yes both.  Have a look this for external sharing : http://sharepointmaven.com/setup-external-users-sharepoint/